# change the second datepicker's minDate depending the first one

Tags: jquery-ui, onselect

I have two datePickers in the same page and I wanna change the second datepicker's minDate depending the first one. Here is my code:

```
$("#datepickerDepart" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy", 
                minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
          var m = dateText.substring(0,2);
          var d = dateText.substring(3,5);
          var y = dateText.substring(6,10);
          console.log(d);
          console.log(m);
          console.log(y);
          var newDate = new Date(y,m-1,d);
          console.log(newDate);
          $('#datepickerReturn').val("");
                      $('#datepickerReturn').datepicker({
              dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
              minDate: newDate
          })
             }
});
```

But I have a question, the first time I select a date in the first datePicker, the minDate of second one will be set according to this, but when I reselect the first one, the second datePicker's minDate won't change anymore, it will remain. I don't know why. Please help!!

I just wanna the minDate of the second one will change as long as the selected date of the first one change.

Comment: Please post your complete code and if possible a jsFiddle example.

Comment: Have you seen the [date range demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range)? That should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#strStartDate").datepicker({ 
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', 
  constrainInput: true,
  firstDay: 1,
  hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
  onSelect: function(){
        if ($("#strStartDate").val() > $("#strEndDate").val()){
            $("#strEndDate").val($("#strStartDate").val());
        }
  }
```

});

```
$("#strEndDate").datepicker({ 
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', 
  constrainInput: true,
  firstDay: 1,
  hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
  beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
        inst.settings.minDate = $("#strStartDate").val();
 }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the second `datepicker` incorrectly. I am assuming you have already initialized the second one previously, although your code posted doesn't appear to. You need to use the option syntax when updating it, instead of the constructor.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate

```
$('#datepickerReturn').val("");
$('#datepickerReturn').datepicker({'option','minDate', newDate});
```

Full code:

```
$('#datepickerReturn').datepicker({
              dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
              minDate: 0
          });
$("#datepickerDepart" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy", 
                minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
          var m = dateText.substring(0,2);
          var d = dateText.substring(3,5);
          var y = dateText.substring(6,10);
          console.log(d);
          console.log(m);
          console.log(y);
          var newDate = new Date(y,m-1,d);
          console.log(newDate);
          $('#datepickerReturn').val("");
          $('#datepickerReturn').datepicker({'option','minDate', newDate});
      }
});
```

Comment: Okay. Feel free to give mine a try if what you found doesn't work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can update secodn datepicker's mindate   with following code  :

```
 $( "#ddate" ).datepicker({
showOn: "button",
buttonImage: base_path+"img/date_picker.png",
buttonImageOnly: true,
onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                    $("#rdate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                },
                minDate: 'today'

}); 
$( "#rdate" ).datepicker({
showOn: "button",
buttonImage: base_path+"img/date_picker.png",
buttonImageOnly: true,
  minDate: 'today'

});
```