# Start date should not greater than End date jquery php

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two datepickers,I want start date should not greater than end date or end date should not
less than start date using jquery,
I tried with following code but not working for me,How can i do this ?

```
<script>
$(function() {  
      $( "#to" ).datepicker({   
      defaultDate: "",
         maxDate:"+0d",
      changeMonth: false,   
      numberOfMonths: 1,  
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {  
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate" ,selectedDate ); 
      }  
    });  

  });  
 </script>

<script>
$(function() {  
      $( "#from" ).datepicker({  

      defaultDate: "",
         maxDate:"+0d",
      changeMonth: false,   
      numberOfMonths: 1,  
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {  
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate" ,selectedDate ); 
       }  
    });  

  });  
 </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change the second datepicker's minDate depending the first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632738/change-the-second-datepickers-mindate-depending-the-first-one)

Comment: You should be more precise on "not working for me", does it produce errors? what does it do that you didn't expect?

Comment: add an `onSelect : function(date)` callback to the options, in there pull the date from the other date picker if it's not what you want, return false.  Guess I should have read that duplicate link, basically what I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onSelect event

```js
$(function() {
  $("#from").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "",
    maxDate: "+0d",
    changeMonth: false,
    numberOfMonths: 1,

    onSelect: function(selected) {
      $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
    }
  });

  $("#to").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "",
    maxDate: "+0d",
    changeMonth: false,
    numberOfMonths: 1,

    onSelect: function(selected) {
      $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="from" />
<input type="text" id="to" />
```

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix what do you mean kill the selection? it works for me (Firefox)

Comment: It may have been my browser. one issue is if you pick `March 1` in the second box, and then delete it, your first box is locked in with a max of `March 1`.  So you have to go back to the second, select a larger date then go edit the first one.  You can probably use `blur` to check if the field is empty and reset that to the current date to fix it. It's a minor annoyance.Something like this:  `$("#to").blur(function(){ if($(this).val() == '')  $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", 0); });`